# How to use onSearchRequested() in fragments?

Tags: android

I am developing an application which uses fragments,here is my problem.

1.In older versions of android  we can override the onSearchRequested() method in activities.

2.But where as in the fragments we can't override the onSearchRequested(), how to implement this method in fragments.

Thanks,
Nikhilreddy.

Comment: how did you eventually do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try `getActivity().onSearchRequested();`